# Unable to install NetworkManager from source

Tags: software-installation, network-manager

I am trying to upgrade NetworkManager to 1.23-1 on Ubuntu 19.10, to overcome a bug in 1.20.

I installed to `/usr` with the following process:

- downloaded the latest tar archive and extracted it to `/usr`.
- edited `autogen.sh`, appending `--prefix=/usr` to the end of *Configure*.
- as root:

  ```
  dpkg --force-all --remove network-manager
  cd /usr/NetworkManager-1.23.1    
  ./autogen.sh
  make
  make install
  ```

When I reboot, `NetworkManager.service` fails to start, and `systemctl status NetworkManager` gives this:

```
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/local/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service.d
           └─NetworkManager-ovs.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-02-06 20:00:03 GMT; 3min 28s ago
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
  Process: 17793 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
 Main PID: 17793 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 06 20:00:03 luke-pc systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, sch
Feb 06 20:00:03 luke-pc systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counte
Feb 06 20:00:03 luke-pc systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
Feb 06 20:00:03 luke-pc systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 06 20:00:03 luke-pc systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 06 20:00:03 luke-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
```

On manually running sudo /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon --log-level=debug, journactl -xe gives this:

```
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <info>  [1581019645.9276] NetworkManager (version 1.23.1) is starting... (after a restart)
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <info>  [1581019645.9277] Read config: /usr/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf)
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <debug> [1581019645.9277] CONFIG: config-data[0x560dc8ad11b0]: 2 groups
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <debug> [1581019645.9277] CONFIG: 
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <debug> [1581019645.9277] CONFIG: [connectivity]
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <debug> [1581019645.9277] CONFIG:   uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <debug> [1581019645.9277] CONFIG: 
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <debug> [1581019645.9277] CONFIG: [device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <debug> [1581019645.9278] CONFIG:   match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <debug> [1581019645.9278] CONFIG:   wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <debug> [1581019645.9278] CONFIG:   wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <debug> [1581019645.9278] CONFIG:   ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <debug> [1581019645.9278] CONFIG: 
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <debug> [1581019645.9278] CONFIG: # no-auto-default file "/usr/var/lib/NetworkManager/no-auto-default.state"
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <warn>  [1581019645.9278] config: unknown key 'wifi.cloned-mac-address' in section [device-mac-addr-change-wifi] of file '/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf'
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <warn>  [1581019645.9278] config: unknown key 'ethernet.cloned-mac-address' in section [device-mac-addr-change-wifi] of file '/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf'
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <debug> [1581019645.9279] config: state: missing state file "/usr/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state": No such file or directory
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <debug> [1581019645.9279] WEXT support is enabled
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <debug> [1581019645.9280] create NMDBusManager singleton (5a8c0467649cc135)
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <error> [1581019645.9307] bus-manager: fatal failure to acquire D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Connection ":1.161" is not allowed to own the service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" due to security policies in the configuration file
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <info>  [1581019645.9308] exiting (error)
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <debug> [1581019645.9312] disposing NMDBusManager singleton (5a8c0467649cc135)
Feb 06 20:07:25 luke-pc NetworkManager[11012]: <debug> [1581019645.9312] disposing NMConfig singleton (d261c54ce82089be)
```

Can anyone help? I presume that NetworkManager.service or something was not configured properly on installing from source?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the mentioned bug in 1.20?

Comment: Wireless connection is unpredictable and sometimes times fails shortly after authentication, or can drop without warning.  This only happens with the router at home, which was recently upgraded. Error message: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/1 ... CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=..................... reason=3 . I thought it might be this bug: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/issues/232, so I wanted to see whether upgrading networkmanager would fix it.

Comment: Now that I look again, I would prefer to upgrade, but I suppose I could try downgrading.

Comment: Downgrading to a previous version turned out to be successful.

Answer (score 1):

For me it seems that you are using incorrect method to install from source.
You may miss some Debian/Ubuntu-related patches or something similar.
Consider to remove your installation of NetworkManager and then proceed with the method below.

You have to install all build-dependencies with:

```
# get build dependencies
sudo apt-get build-dep network-manager

# get tools
sudo apt-get install build-essential dpkg-dev debhelper devscripts
```

and then download [deb-package from latest development release](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/network-manager):

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager/network-manager_1.22.4-1ubuntu2.dsc
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager/network-manager_1.22.4.orig.tar.xz
tar -xf network-manager_1.22.4.orig.tar.xz
cd NetworkManager-1.22.4/
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager/network-manager_1.22.4-1ubuntu2.debian.tar.xz
tar -xf network-manager_1.22.4-1ubuntu2.debian.tar.xz

# compile deb-packages from source code
fakeroot debian/rules binary

# install resulting deb-packages
sudo apt install ../*.deb
```

and then reboot.

Comment: That's a kind of wrong way too. I would do it by `fakeroot debian/rules binary`

Comment: @Pilot6, I found that this were recommended in https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial . Thanks!

Comment: I didn't "find" it anywhere, but I permanently build packages from source. There are many all kinds of not very good tutorials. This way does work, but it is too long to explain why this is not perfect.

Comment: Hi, you linked to v1.22.  I need v1.23, which is not released for Ubuntu development...